# Question about Volume Booster App

Tags: volume, dell

This is on a Dell Venue Tablet. The multimedia volume on the tablet was very very low from the time of purchase. I installed an app called **Volume Booster** - the app ran & said it has increased the volume by 23%. And the volume has gotten louder.

I have a few questions

- How do these apps increase the volume?
- Is it safe to use?
- Now that it has increased the volume - can I uninstall the app or will I lose volume if I uninstall it - the reason I want to uninstall it is because it advertises other apps for installation & my wife who uses the tablet isn't tech savvy & she may end up installing some rubbish accidentally.

This is an unrooted tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I probably won´t answer all you ask, but from my experience, these apps on android simply max out all volume levels that a user can max out himself manually. Could you please give me a direct Google Play link to what app exactly are you referring to? I can give it a try (I am interested myself).

As far as I know, the only thing in what boosting volume could be hurtful is that some already volume-maxed out tracks could be too much for your speaker and the sound would become distorted. I don´t think that there could be any physical damaged done (moreover when its not rooted).

As to what those 23% could be (after 77% of max sound volume), isn't that the exact percent when android ask user if he is really sure he wants to increase volume up to 100% and gives the warning? Some music apps are not able to show this warning so the volume simply won´t go above.